# Kusto query difference of an "Odometer" value over specified timespan with rollovers to 0

Tags: database, time-series, kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I've got a bit of a potentially unusual requirement for a KQL query. It boils down to finding the difference of the first instance to the last instance of a value within a specified timespan.

Say we got the following schema with `value` being incremented at random times:

```
"TableName": OdometerData,
"Schema": timestamp:datetime, value:real
```

Querying this is simple enough with for example:

```
OdometerData
| where timestamp between (ago(7d) .. now())
| summarize diff=(max(value) - min(value))
```

The issue is that this `value` field will rollover and reset to 0 when it reaches a predetermined value. This means that the query above would not return the proper value if a rollover happened during the span of the query. Correct result would be to get a value that "continues" the value after the rollover instead of resetting to 0 and summarizing the difference.

My question is if there is some built-in functionality or perhaps a way to use a materialized view to keep a value that will continue to increment independent of the `value` rollover? Or would this be better solved with pre-processing of the data before writing it into the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an interesting scenario.  I don't believe there is anything built-in which would fix this entire use but since it's KQL there is usually at least one way of doing it.

Personally I'd approach this with [windows functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions).  Namely [`serialise`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/serializeoperator), [`next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/nextfunction) and [`row_cumsum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction) which does the incrementation you're asking for in your question. Also add in a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) statement for some logic.

An interesting possibly edge case I've commented in the code below is what happens if the value is the same across two sequential `value` pairs?  Do you assume it's gone full circle or assume it's not changed?

Since you also mention pre-processing before this data gets ingested that could absolutely be another sensible option too.

```
let RollOverPoint = 100; //When does our data rollover
let OdometerData = range timestamp from startofweek(ago(28d)) to endofday(now()) step 1h //Generate some data
| extend value = rand(RollOverPoint); //Assuming Odometer rolls over at x and flips to 0
OdometerData
| where timestamp between (ago(7d) .. now())
| order by timestamp asc
| serialize 
| extend NextValue = next(value, 1)
| extend SumAmount = case (
  NextValue == value, 0, //Deal with identical sequences
  NextValue > value, toint(NextValue - value),
  NextValue < value, toint(((RollOverPoint) - value) + NextValue),
  0
  )
| serialize TotalOdometer = row_cumsum(SumAmount)
| project timestamp, value, TotalOdometer
//| summarize arg_min(StartTime = timestamp, LowestValue = value), arg_max(EndTime = timestamp, TotalValue = TotalOdometer)
```

| timestamp | value | TotalOdometer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25T19:00:00.0000000Z | 20.0 | 80 |
| 2023-10-25T20:00:00.0000000Z | 0.0 | 102 |
| 2023-10-25T21:00:00.0000000Z | 22.0 | 156 |
| 2023-10-25T22:00:00.0000000Z | 76.0 | 188 |
| 2023-10-25T23:00:00.0000000Z | 8.0 | 249 |
| 2023-10-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 69.0 | 338 |
| 2023-10-26T01:00:00.0000000Z | 58.0 | 372 |
| 2023-10-26T02:00:00.0000000Z | 92.0 | 380 |
| 2023-10-26T03:00:00.0000000Z | 0.0 | 435 |
| 2023-10-26T04:00:00.0000000Z | 55.0 | 500 |
| etc | etc | etc |

Or example output with the `summarize` above.

| StartTime | LowestValue | EndTime | TotalValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25T20:00:00.0000000Z | 61 | 2023-11-01T19:00:00.0000000Z | 8337 |

Comment: The assumption if the value is identical would be that it has not changed rather than it having gone full-circle like you covered in your case statement. I believe your solution fits my needs very well. The more I learn about KQL the more impressed I am, very clever solution!